# How does one create a way to perform the following in C#?

Tags: c#

How does one create a way to perform the following in C#?

```
If Test-A fails AND Test-B passes
Then the FILE is updated to only have failed the Test-A
If Test-A passes AND Test-B fails
Then the FILE is updated to only have failed the Test-B
If Test-A fails AND Test-B fails
Then the FILE is updated to fail BOTH the Test-A and the Test-B
If Test-A passes AND Test-B passes
Then the FILE is updated to pass BOTH the Test-A and the Test-B
```

I am trying to help my nephew with his hw but I have no idea.

Comment: This would be better solved if you went through a C# tutorial for conditionals and file processing. Usually people ask specific code questions after they've written code that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

You literally wrote the solution, it's just a matter of translating it:

```
class Test
{
    public void Update(bool a, bool b)
    {
        if (a)
        {
            if (b)
            {
                // TODO    
            }
            else
            {
                // TODO    
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (b)
            {
                // TODO    
            }
            else
            {
                // TODO    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All you have to do now is implement the *then* statements.